# Convert couple of characters to int

Tags: java

How can I convert couple of characters to int, to keep the question simple let's assume this :

```
char c1 = '1';
char c2 = '4';
char c3 = '5';
```

What would be the efficient way to get `145` type int.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int myInt = Integer.parseInt(""+c1+c2+c3);
```

`""+c1` gives you a String containing the char `c1`, to which you append the characters `c2` and `c3`. Then you use `parseInt()` to convert it to an integer.

A more straightforward (but less robust) method would be this:

```
int myInt = 100*(c1-'0') + 10*(c2-'0') + (c3-'0');
```

`c1-'0'` gives you the number represented by `c1` as opposed to the character code. Then you simply shift things to the correct decimal places and add.

Comment: Note that if this is done in a tight loop, you should use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and not concat on strings, to create a little less objects. [or your second suggested approach]. If it is not the case - the difference is obviously neglectable.

Comment: @amit `""+c1+c2+c3` already uses a stringbuilder (or buffer? well something) anyhow.

Comment: @Voo: It does uses `StringBuilder`, true - but it also creates 2 intermediate strings that you will not need. This can be avoided if you use a `StringBuilder` and build the resulting string yourself.

Comment: @amit Just checked the bytecode: We're loading one interned string (the `""`, so nothing created there), then call `append(char)` and finally `toString`. Optimal code as far as I can see (well the append of the empty string isn't but the jit will take care of that I'm pretty sure) and only one string object created - and that we need anyhow because `parseInt` expects it.

Comment: @tskuzzy nice one dude, I was parsing file when data was in "columns", and I used substring to get some data(int data) it took about 50ms per record. Now when I use your trick with characters into int avoiding strings the processing time decreased from 50 to between 20-30ms, kick ass. thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
int myInt = (c1 - '0') * 100 + (c2 - '0') * 10 + (c3 - '0');
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more general method to convert a char array to int:

```
int valueOf(char[] input){
  int result = 0;
  for(char c : input) {
    result *= 10;
    result += Character.digit(c, 10);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most correct way to convert a single digit character to an `int` is [`Character.digit(char ch, int radix)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit%28char,%20int%29), which can handle values in bases besides 10.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are ultimately backed by a `char[]`, so you could do the following:

```
char c1 = '1';
char c2 = '4';
char c3 = '5';
int converted = Integer.parseInt(new String(new char[]{c1, c2, c3}));
```

There are probably several other perfectly good ways to do this.